# If statement with many if else

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script to set the Computer name and Static IP address of a bunch of computers using a script and I am getting an end of file error when run.  Here is a small sample of the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
serial=`/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | /usr/bin/awk '/Serial\ Number\ \(system\)/ {print $NF}'`

if test "$serial" == "C07M802Z4E825DY3J"
then
    scutil --set ComputerName "qa-mac-1"
    scutil --set LocalHostName "qa-mac-1"

    networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery "Ethernet" on
    networksetup -setmanual Ethernet 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.128 10.1.1.129
    networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 10.2.76.98 10.2.76.97
    networksetup -setsearchdomains Ethernet mycompany.com mycompanycorp.com us.mycompany.com
else
    if test "$serial" == "C07M803JDLSY3J"
    then
        scutil --set ComputerName "qa-mac-2"
        scutil --set LocalHostName "qa-mac-2"

        networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery "Ethernet" on
        networksetup -setmanual Ethernet 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.128 10.1.1.129
        networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 10.2.76.98 10.2.76.97
        networksetup -setsearchdomains Ethernet mycompany.com mycompanycorp.com us.mycompany.com

        if test "$serial" == "C0737951JDLSY3J"
        then
            scutil --set ComputerName "qa-mac-3"
            scutil --set LocalHostName "qa-mac-3"

            networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery "Ethernet" on
            networksetup -setmanual Ethernet 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.128 10.1.1.129
            networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 10.2.76.98 10.2.76.97
            networksetup -setsearchdomains Ethernet mycompany.com mycompanycorp.com us.mycompany.com
        fi

        exit 0
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) (the first item) and [edit] your question to make the script readable.

Comment: Every `if` statement must have a match `fi` 

Also `else if` is not the same as `elif`

Comment: Another note: when posting questions about issues where you get an error, include the _exact_ error message you get. Usually, the readers of your question don't have your system at hand, so they might not be able to reproduce the error. But showing it up front might make it much easier for them to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: @Georgyo, when you post edits like that, remove the extra empty lines too! The only reason they're there is that the poster used them as a substitute for code formatting. The code is still unreadable because of them.

Comment: @rdagel415 Proper indentation and formatting helps to keep an overview of your code; make a habit out of it. The matter with your `if`s has already been pointed out; after the reformatting it should be clear where the issue(s) are. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for hints how you can further improve your question. You're welcome.

Comment: Download `shellcheck`, or use it online. Both at shellcheck.net. Package is also in some distros. It flags five errors that would fix this issue, although Andy has posted a much improved version in his answer. I notice you tagged this `bash` but the shebang is `sh`. In Bash, I would set up corresponding arrays for serial, name, address, as that would be far easier to maintain and extend.

Answer (score 5):

Your script, as written, has a ton of code duplication that will make it hard to work with when things change.  Beyond the `if`/`else` vs `if`/`elif`, I suggest you code conditionally handle the parts that *vary* and do everything else once.

Based on my quick scan of your script, the only things that vary between the different serial numbers is the hostname and IP address.  Given that, your script could be:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# I tried to minimize the changes to your original to avoid distracting from the
# point I was trying to make, but alas...
# This is functionally equivalent to what you had originally.
serial="$(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | /usr/bin/awk '/Serial Number \(system\)/ {print $NF}')"
name=""
address=""

if [ "${serial}" = "C07M802Z4E825DY3J" ]; then
    name="qa-mac-1"
    address="10.1.1.1"
elif [ "${serial}" = "C07M803JDLSY3J" ]; then
    name="qa-mac-2"
    address="10.1.1.2"
elif [ "${serial}" = "C0737951JDLSY3J" ]; then
    name="qa-mac-3"
    address="10.1.1.3" # You had 10.1.1.2 here, I'm guessing it should have been .3
else
    echo "Serial ${serial} is unsupported"
    exit 1
fi

scutil --set ComputerName "${name}"
scutil --set LocalHostName "${name}"

networksetup -setproxyautodiscovery "Ethernet" on
networksetup -setmanual Ethernet "${address}" 255.255.255.128 10.1.1.129
networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 10.2.76.98 10.2.76.97
networksetup -setsearchdomains Ethernet mycompany.com mycompanycorp.com us.mycompany.com
```

Answer (score 4):

For the if/then/elif... part, maybe you can try with CASE instead

It works in bash as well.

```
#!/bin/sh
...
case $serial in
   "C07M802Z4E825DY3J")
      name="qa-mac-1"
      address="10.1.1.1"
      ;;
   "C07M803JDLSY3J")
      name="qa-mac-2"
      address="10.1.1.2"
      ;;
   "C0737951JDLSY3J")
      name="qa-mac-3"
      address="10.1.1.3"
      ;;
   \?) # incorrect option
      echo "Error: Invalid option"
      exit;;
esac
```

Comment: "Invalid option"? Note that `\?)` matches a literal question mark, that looks like something that would be used with `getopts`. Something like `*) echo "Unknown serial number";;` might be more descriptive here.